# Install libraries from computer

Tags: pip, toolchain

I'm currently searching a tool to install on a Raspi libraries, but from a computer.
SSH can be a solution but I'm searching a tool where you can see the installed package and the one that can be upgraded.

If the same tool could also exist for python pip libraries it will be awesome!
I know that it's possible to upgrade pip module from Jetbrain PyCharm but only in the pro version.

Thanks

Comment: what kind of libraries you are referring to? Python library? Can you describe the problem you are facing? and what exactly is your question?

Comment: I'm just asking if a software for PC is available to install with a friendly UI libraries remotely on the Raspberry.
I'm currently using ssh with commands "sudo apt-get install ......"

Comment: *"a tool where you can see the installed package the one that can be upgraded"* -> Plain 'ol `apt update; apt upgrade` already does this.  The first one tells you how many packages have updates, the second one gives you a list of them with version information.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want a GUI front end to the package manager.

Perhaps google for "apt-get GUI raspbian".

That will give a hit such as this one suggesting [synaptic](https://neil-black.co.uk/raspberrypi/install-gui-package-manager-on-the-raspberry-pi/).

You can view the screen on another machine using something like VNC.

See [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/README.md) for instructions.

Comment: It's a good idea but I'm using the lite version of Raspbian

Comment: @BaptisteM I'm not sure what you actually want.  Perhaps look at `apt-cache policy`

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are looking for a package manager that runs on a pc but will not install software on the pc but on a remote raspi. As far as I know such a package manager isn't available. It must run on the machine where to install software.

This is possible with *ssh* that give you a shell from the remote raspi. In this shell you can run software on the remote raspi, also its package managers `apt` or `apt-get` and friends. You may run `aptitude` on the raspi in the console from *ssh*. It is a menu oriented package manager in text mode. If you want to run packet managers on the raspi with a GUI you must install the X-server on it for graphical support or use the full version of *Raspbian*. Then instead of *ssh* you can connect to the remote raspi from your pc with *VNC* and run software (packet managers) with GUI on it, for example the *Synaptic Package Manager*.